# jquery.on('click', function() {...}); not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently (trying) building a photo tiles gallery for my website. So when you click on an image, it resize it to the entire screen.

The problem is that once it is zoom, my `jquery.on('click', function() {...})` won't trigger, and I don't know why.

For simplicity, here's my demo: 
https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B2DQgwgiU8LZbGhsbkxjdlRpR3M/

In the browser's inspector, you can see the `index.html`, `style.css` and, more specifictly, the `script.js` file which is were the problem is.

Thanks for helping me in my initiation with jQuery (javascript)!

Comment: You haven't supplied an element to which the click event is attached. Normally it would be something like `$(element).on('click', function()...`. Or if you need event delegation: `$(document).on('click', 'element', function()...`

Comment: `For simplicity` you should have posted relevant code in question itself...

Comment: `jquery('selector').on('click', function()...`

Comment: @Andy and JqueryKing Yes, I have passed a selector in the function. jQuery.function_name is just a shorter way to writte the function so people know which function on which plugin I am using.

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry for that, it was simplier for me to simply give you the link to my project instead of copy/pasting a lot of code lines in this post. I just didn't have time for it (I'm no longer on my computer). I will try to put it soon.

Comment: @lolgab123 That's ok but that just because once your issue will be fixed, this question would be outdated (kind of) for futur readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this because when you assign click event `img-container` div is not exist

```
 $(document).on( 'click', '.img-container', function () {

 });
```

Comment: Woo, I wasn't knowing this syntax for the click function... Will definitly try that. BUT can you put multiple elements in the arguments at the same time? Like $(document).on('click', '.img-container', 'img', 'p', [...and so on...], function() {...?

Comment: @lolgab123 the second parameter is a string selector, so you can pass any valid selector: `$(document).on( 'click', '.img-container, img, p', function () {`

Comment: @A.Wolff Wow... ok, I will also try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please, the next time, provide the key code here, not in a drive file, and for the complete example use something like codepen or jsfiddle. The way you make your question takes a lot of work for me to review it and make a working example, if you make a jsfiddle, I only have to modify it.

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ouno09f/2/ or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNGqPg

```
$(function() {   

$('.photo-tiles img').each(function() 
    {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="tile"><div class="image"></div></div>');

        if ( $(this).width() / $(this).height() < 5/3 )
        {
            $(this).addClass('width');
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).addClass('height');
        }
    });

    //Correct click syntax
    $('.photo-tiles').on('click', 'img', function() 
    {
        url = $(this).attr('src');
        caption = $(this).data('caption');
        if (caption == undefined) caption = "";

        $('<div class="img-container"><img src="' + url + '"><p class="caption">' + caption + '</p></div>')
            .appendTo('body')
            .velocity({
                opacity: 1
            }, {
                duration: 300
            });
    });

    //You can't attach the event to the .img-container element because that is the element you're adding and removing. The event must be attached to a element that persis9t on all your flow, in this case, the body (because you're adding the new element to the end of the body
    $('body').on('click', '.img-container', function() 
    {
        var imgContainer = $(this);
        imgContainer.velocity({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 300,
            complete: function() { 
                //Remove the clicked element on the completed animation
                imgContainer.remove();
            }
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: I put comments in everything I changed it...it works no? why is not the answer?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet, I'm not on my computer, and my iPad lags too much for jsFiddle... As soon as I test it, I will let you know.

Comment: I created in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNGqPg I'm curious if works better on iPad than jsfiddle

Comment: Clearly works better on Codepen, don't know why... But thanks! It totally works!

Answer (score -1):

After each zoom I would suspect you must retrigger

```
jquery.on('click', function() {...})
```

as it seems to become undone after each zoom.

Comment: OH, OK! I was thinking that the click function was always re-checking by itself if the element to be clicked was existing... thanks then, I will check on that